# IBM websphere and BPM SSO

Tags: java

I have two websphere servers.One server has java web application deployed and other has BPM processes.I have configured SSO between two servers,both servers admin console is opening with SSO.

I have to open IBM BPM coach inside my web application with SSO, What should i do in my web application to open coach directly without given user and password.

Comment: Try to ask in the [IBM BPM forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002382), you may get better answer there.

Answer (score -1):

For establishing SSO between multiple Websphere servers, all you have to do is enable SSO at server level, ensure that LTPA token is generated on successful login to your webapplication. Once LTPA is created, the same is propogated to the 2nd webapp/any other webapp which you access since the cookie created by the Websphere exists in browser and can be consumed by any Websphere server that participates in this SSO.

I am as well trying to setup the SSO between 2 websphere servers but i am unable to get the admin console apps logged in seamlessly.

Can you confirm the steps that you followed? I hope you are using custom standalone registry(referring to user.props & group.props for eg)